# AWS ECS Container Agent only registers 1 vCPU but 2 are available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

In the AWS console I setup a ECS cluster. I registered a EC2 container instance on a m3.medium, which has 2vCPUs. In the ECS console it says only 1024 CPU units are available.

Is this expected behavior?
Should the m3.medium instance not make 2048 CPU units available for the cluster?

I have been searching the documentation. I find a lot of explanation of how tasks consume and reserve CPU, but nothing about how the container agent contributes to the available CPU.

[ECS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eg1J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tldr

> In the AWS console I setup a ECS cluster. I registered a EC2 container > instance on a m3.medium, which has 2vCPUs. In the ECS console it says > only 1024 CPU units are available. > > Is this expected behavior?

yes

> Should the m3.medium instance not make 2048 CPU units available for
> the cluster?

No. `m3.medium` instances only have 1vCPU (1024 CPU units)

> I have been searching the documentation. I find a lot of explanation
> of how tasks consume and reserve CPU, but nothing about how the
> container agent contributes to the available CPU.

There prob isn't going to be much official documentation on the container agent performance specifically, but my best recommendation is to pay attention to issues,releases,changelogs, etc in the [github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues?q=is%3Aissue+cpu+) and [github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init/tree/master) projects

---

### long version

The `m3` instance types are essentially deprecated at this point (not even listed on main instance details page), but you'll be able to  see the `m3.medium` only has **1vCPU** in the the details table on kinda hard to find [ec2/previous-generations page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/)

```
Instance Family     Instance Type   Processor Arch  vCPU    Memory (GiB)    Instance Storage (GB)   EBS-optimized Available Network Performance
...
General purpose m3.medium   64-bit  1   3.75    1 x 4   -   Moderate
...
```

According to this [knowledge-center/ecs-cpu-allocation article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-cpu-allocation/), **1 vCPU** is equivalent to **1024 CPU Units** as described in

> Amazon ECS uses a standard unit of measure for CPU resources called
> CPU units. 1024 CPU units is the equivalent of 1 vCPU.
>
> For example, 2048 CPU units is equal to 2 vCPU.

Capacity planning for ECS cluster on an EC2 can be... a journey... and will be highly dependent on your specific workload. You're unlikely to find a "one size" fits all documentation/how-to source but I can recommend the following starting points:

1. [The capacity section of the ECS bestpractices guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/capacity.html)
2. [The cluster capacity providers section of the ECS Developers guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html)

Running on an `m3.medium` is prob a problem in and of itself since the smallest types i've in the documentation almost are `c5.large`, `r5.large` and `m5.large` which have **2vCPU**

Comment: Looks like the source of my problem was simply that I misread the m3.medium spec somewhere [facepalm]. For some reason I was convinced it had 2 vCPUs.